# MYSQL query in a finite loop with sqlalchemy lost connection

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, database-connection, mysql-python

I`m building a finance web app with flask, sqlalchemy and MYSQL.

I try to query a collection of trading data in a stocks list loop, but it shows lost connection after some steps (about first 5~10 steps randomly).

```
for stock in stocks: #about 2000~3000 items
   engine = create_engine(os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE_URI')
   sql = 'select * from ..."
   df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
   return df
```

The error message is as following:

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you closing your connection? If you do `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` in MySQL you can see all your open connections.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reusing a single engine object. First [create](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/engine.html#establishing-connectivity-the-engine) the engine object.

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE_URI')

for stock in stocks: #about 2000~3000 items
  sql = 'select * from ...'
  df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine)
  return df
```

Although this doesn't make a lot of sense because there is a `return` statement inside this loop so the loop never finishes.

Maybe make a list and return that instead?

```
engine = create_engine(os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE_URI')
values = []
for stock in stocks: #about 2000~3000 items
  sql = 'select * from ...'
  values.append(pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine))
return values
```